# Not Skipping exceptions in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Spring batch is not able to skip below exception. Can any body suggest what did I miss here?

```
<batch:job id="runPromotion">   
        <batch:step id="readPromotionStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="processPromotion"></batch:tasklet>
            <batch:next on="SUCCESS" to="getPromotionalPoints" />
            <batch:end on="FAILED"></batch:end> 
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="queryProvider"/>           
            </batch:listeners>          
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="getPromotionalPoints">      
            <batch:tasklet >            
                <batch:chunk reader="transactionDataReader" writer="userPromotionWriter" commit-interval="100" skip-limit="100">                
                <batch:skippable-exception-classes >
                    <batch:include class="org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException"/>
                    <batch:include class="javax.persistence.PersistenceException"/>
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="queryProvider"/>           
            </batch:listeners>


        </batch:step>   

    </batch:job>
```

**below is error while running batch :**

> 2013-08-24 14:43:16,451 - [main] WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
>   2013-08-24 14:43:16,451 - [main] ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:144 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'promotion_id'
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'promotion_id'
>           at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)

Comment: post full strack trace,please

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

you will notice that *PersistenceException* is the actual error thrown and *ConstraintViolationException* is the cause. This is why adding *ConstraintViolationException* to *skippable-exception-classes* does not work, but I am surprised that even *PersistenceException* did not work for you. It worked for me (but I used Java configuration by the way). Moreover, since you are also adding *PersistenceException* (which is a super-class to *ConstraintViolationException*)  to *skippable-exception-classes*, adding *ConstraintViolationException* seems redundant.

I assume that you only wish to skip *ConstraintViolationException*. I have tried two solutions (but using Java configuration):

1. Implement SkipPolicy to create a custom skipper. Notice how we check if the cause of the thrown exception is *ConstraintViolationException*:

   ```
   package pkg;

   import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;
   import org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException;
   import org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.SkipLimitExceededException;
   import org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.SkipPolicy;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   public class ConstraintViolationExceptionSkipper implements SkipPolicy {

       private int skipLimit;

       @Override
       public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable t, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
         if(t instanceof PersistenceException && 
             t.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
           return true;
         }
         return false;
       }

       public void setSkipLimit(int skipLimit) {
         this.skipLimit = skipLimit;
       }
   }
   ```

   And set the above skipper as the *skip-policy* in the chunk and get rid of the *skippable-exception-classes* block. Also notice how *skip-limit* is set here:

   ```
   <batch:chunk reader="transactionDataReader" writer="userPromotionWriter" commit-interval="100" 
       skip-policy="skipPolicy" />

   <bean id="skipPolicy" class=pkg.ConstraintViolationExceptionSkipper">
     <property name="skipLimit" value="100" />
   </bean>
   ```
2. Modify your writer to catch the PersistenceException and rethrow it as a ConstraintVioaltionException. I am not sure how you have implemented *userPromotionWriter* but below is a sample implementation. It uses JPA for persistence, flushes EntityManager explicitly and catches and throws a new exception like I just said:

   ```
   package pkg;

   import java.util.List;

   import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
   import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

   import org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException;
   import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   @Component("userPromotionWriter")
   public class UserPromotionWriter implements ItemWriter<User> {

     @PersistenceContext
     private EntityManager entityManger;

     @Override
     public void write(List<? extends User> users) throws Exception {
         for(User user : users) {
           entityManger.persist(user);
           try {
               entityManger.flush();
           } catch(Exception e) {
               if(e.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
                   throw new ConstraintViolationException("Tried to insert a User record with a non-unique user_id of " + user.getUserId(), null, null);
               }
               throw e;
           }
           finally {
             entityManger.clear();
           }
         }
      }
   }
   ```

   Now since the exception being thrown is ConstraintViolationException (and not PersistenceException), the following will work just fine:

   `<batch:chunk reader="transactionDataReader" writer="userPromotionWriter" commit-interval="100" skip-limit="100">
       <batch:skippable-exception-classes >
         <batch:include class="org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException"/>
       </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
   </batch:chunk>`